# Measures appear blank when publishing power bi report

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am working with measurements in power bi first I create a measurement for total sales using SUM, and to obtain today's sales I use a calendar table that is related to my sales table, all good when I work in power bi dektop shows me today's sales on a card but when the report is published, the card appears in (BLANK) and also all the graphs that I use with that measure appear blank.

What could be the problem?

```
Total sales = SUM(Sales[amount])

Sales today = CALCULATE([Total sales],Calendar[Date]=TODAY())
```

Comment: It could be that the server time is different from your local desktop time (if you are located far from the server time zone), and TODAY() might return a different date, which you might not have in your Calendar. Try to put TODAY() on a card to see if that's the case.

Comment: @RADO yes, the server time tells me that it is already February 13, how can I get the local time?

Comment: This is a difficult problem; you can get some ideas here: https://radacad.com/solving-dax-time-zone-issue-in-power-bi

Comment: It could also be an issue with regional settings for date format. I once faced a similar issue that when I uploaded the file, any time related measure would show as blank. It worked after I've refreshed the data in the service.